# simultaneous null band for uniform QQ plot in R

Tags: r, simultaneous, quantile

This question is about convenient way of plotting simultaneous null band based on pointwise quantile estimates in R. Suppose I obtain a vector of p-values, and I want to see, by using uniform QQ plot, if its distribution is close to a uniform distribution (...and if not, which points "stand out", i.e. fall outside the band). Here is an example (where `u_obs` denotes p-values not necessarily from a uniform distribution -- for illustration purpose only):

```
library(gap)
u_obs = qqrunif(1000)
qqunif(u_obs,pch=21,bg="blue",bty="n")
```

According to the nonparametric approach discussed on page 5, Figure 1 (bottom left panel) of this paper: http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~buja/PAPERS/paper-sim.pdf, we can do 10,000 simulations and get the lower and upper 5% quantiles if a 90% simultaneous bound is desired.

My questions are:

1. Is there an R package/code snippets that are able to perform this task efficiently? I think this belongs to the "functional data analysis" realm, but I am not quite sure.
2. What inference can we make from the simultaneous null bound of a uniform QQ plot? Examining those points that fall outside the bands? How many points do I expect to be reasonably outside the band if the true distribution of the p-values is uniform (i.e. coming from the null)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's simultaneous or not, but you should look at `car::qqPlot()` and `mgcv::qq.gam()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [?qqPlot](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/car/html/qq.plot.html) function in the [car package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html).  This will plot a confidence band for you (you just have to tell it which distribution you are interested in).

```
library(car)
set.seed(9)
u_obs <- runif(100)
windows()
  qqPlot(u_obs, distribution="unif")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the comment! Yes, it is very close to what I want. When I checked the help manual of `qqPlot`, specifically `qqPlot.lm`, I notice that the `simulate` argument, if TRUE, calculates confidence envelope by parametric bootstrap, but it is for `lm` object only. The method is due to Atkinson (1985). I am hoping to get `qqPlot.default` work using parametric bootstrap to get the (simultaneous) confidence bands. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a least annoying that the theory line does not go through [0,0].

Comment: I suppose you could try to code that up from scratch, @alittleboy, but I don't know of a function that does it. I tried `mod <- lm(u_obs~1)`, but the only distributions that `qqPlot.lm` will accept are "norm" & "t". OTOH, the confidence envelope that's plotted does come from theory, I believe, but seems to take the line as it's reference. In light of DWin's comment, it might be better to use the `line="robust"` option.

Comment: @gung: yes, `line=robust` works to get the ref line passing `(0,0)`. Here is a more fundamental issue: how do we interpret the resultant QQ plot? Expect 5% to be outside the band? BTW, is this band a "simultaneous" one? The author did superimpose the band for some reason, but I am unsure how to use it. Thanks!